# Why are 1982 and 1983 MS-6x Quarters so Expensive?

Tags: coins

I've been shopping to fill four holes in my Washington Quarters coin album: 1982-P/D and 1983-P/D. I understand that there were no official Mint Sets made that year. Mintage figures, on the order of four to five hundred million each, are on par with any other clad quarter. Looking at the [PCGS Price Guide](https://www.pcgs.com/prices/priceguidedetail.aspx?ms=1&pr=1&sp=1&c=112&title=washington+quarter), there's nothing remarkable about these quarters. About a dollar each in MS-low-sixties condition. I have not been able to find them for much less than ten dollars each [on eBay](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=1982-P&_osacat=39461&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.X1982-P+BU.TRS0&_nkw=1982-P+BU&_sacat=39461).

I get it that the price in a book or a web page does not dictate the value of an item, rather it's what the next person is willing to pay for the item. Still, there seems to be a wide disparity between what I would expect the cost of these quarters to be, and what people are willing to sell them for.

So my question: What is driving the apparent cost of these seemingly common clad quarters?

Comment: Have you looked at completed auctions on ebay?

Comment: This is more a forum about personal finance than about Numismatics. I'm hesitant to call this off-topic, given that it's literally about *money*, but if you're focused more on the collectiblity of coins rather than their investment value, I'm not sure you're going to get a lot of response.

Comment: Agreed, @PeterCooperJr. thing is, there's no numismatics forum on StackExchange and this is the closest thing to it. Searching the tag of coins, there are questions along these lines, but we're in agreement that considering this to be on topic is a stretch.

Comment: @stannius, thanks for the clue. Perusing the sales, they seem to average a more reasonable five or six dollars per coin compared to the average ask price that tops ten bucks. Still, this is an enormous disparity given mintage figures for these coins as well as PCGS prices.

Comment: @BobKaufman - I know nothing about collecting, but I'd hazard a guess that the reason they cost so much is the same reason that you don't already have them (whatever that is).  Which may be circular reasoning.

Comment: I once paid $50 for an obscure VHS tape because it was the last one I needed for my collection of Arnold Schwarzenegger movies. I'm not sure that proves anything either way about your obscure(?) coins. Other than, sometimes the combination of obscure and low-volume can cause price anomalies and fluctuations. If I were you I would set up a search alert on ebay and wait for one of the $5-priced coins to show up.

Comment: @stannius - thing is, these are *not* obscure coins! Mintage figures range from 480 million (1982-D) to 673 million (1983-P) that's on par with any other common date post-1964 quarter that sells for around a buck in MS-6x condition. At 101 million, the 1968-D is the least common and sells for about two bucks, or $30 for a roll of forty.

Comment: Can you just hang out at a local laundromat and ask to inspect everyone's quarters until you find one? :)

Comment: @stannius -- Actually, you've inspired me to consider going to my local credit union (they're nicer than banks about about stuff like that) and cycle through all their rolls until I find them. Of course, given what I value my time at, I suppose I could just shut up and buy then on eBay...